# How to restore original view of Chrome's Inspect Element function

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I seem to have inadvertently changed the default view I get with Chrome's Inspect Element function.  I now get the Console:
[image]

What I want (and used to get) is the HTML that I selected:

[image]

Can anyone please advise how to restore this? At the moment I have to manually drag the Console down every time.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually seeing both the console and the elements pane, but the elements pane has zero height.

Drag the bar above the `Console` label down.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to clarify my question.  I know I need to drag it down - that's how I got the second screenshot.  I want it to open up that way so that I don't need to!

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error I found the answer - press `Esc`!

Also its seems that I must have originally have cause it to appear by right clicking on the Elements pane and selecting `Inspect DOM Properties`.